# Updating the Drag-To-Share eXtended share URLs?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, facebook, twitter

How can I update the URLs that [Drag-To-Share eXtended](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dragtoshare-extended/) generates? At least in version 1.13, sharing items for Twitter and Facebook does not produce the proper url string for actually sharing the content on either network.

Facebook, Twitter, and possibly other networks have since changed the url query string methods for sharing...

This would require a quick update to the plugin so it writes up-to-date urls, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: not sure what the question is here - flagged.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar: It is not clear what you are asking here. Is this a request to the plugin authors to fix the plugin, or is this a question on how to fix the plugin yourself? If it is the latter, please edit your question to make this more clear.

Comment: @spartacus @Jan Fabry done

Comment: @vulgarbulgar: Do you know what the URL should look like now? This will make it easier for someone to go in and fix it.

Comment: @Jan Fabry for example: is- http://twitter.com/#!/login?redirect_after_login=%2Fhome%3Fstatus%3DDrag%2520to%2520Share%2520Example%3A%2520http%3A%2F%2Fd2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net%2F467_dragtoShare%2Fsource%2FdragToShare.html

Comment: @Jan Fabry while, should be- http://twitter.com/intent/session?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fjavascript-ajax%2Fdrag-to-share%2F&return_to=%2Fintent%2Ftweet%3Foriginal_referer%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fnet.tutsplus.com%252Ftutorials%252Fjavascript-ajax%252Fdrag-to-share%252F%26text%3DDrag%2Bto%2BShare%2B%257C%2BNettuts%252B%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fnet.tutsplus.com%252Ftutorials%252Fjavascript-ajax%252Fdrag-to-share%252F&text=Drag+to+Share+|+Nettuts%2B&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnet.tutsplus.com%2Ftutorials%2Fjavascript-ajax%2Fdrag-to-share%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLs are constructed [in the `wp-dragtoshare-extended.js` Javascript file](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-dragtoshare-extended/tags/1.13/js/wp-dragtoshare-extended.js?rev=390074#L165).

For most services you can see how the `customUrl` is constructed and change it right there. For Twitter you should look a bit lower, in the `isGD` function, because it does an Ajax request to shorten the link - but maybe this is not needed anymore with the current Twitter sharing service?

If you modify this script you should be aware that the plugin has two versions of the script: `wp-dragtoshare-extended.js` is the normal version, `wp-dragtoshare-extended-packed.js` a minified version to speed up loading. The plugin [loads the packed version](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-dragtoshare-extended/tags/1.13/lib/dtse.functions.php?rev=390074#L15), so either remember to edit that version too (by minifying your edited version) or edit the PHP code so it loads the non-minified version.

Comment: @ Jan Fabry Great info! Thanks so much. I had already started playing with the .js file (I am aware that the minified version is called). Will get back to this thread soon with my results.

Comment: All set! Looks like only the Twitter section needed an update- 'home?status=' to 'intent/tweet?status='